# Getting command line arguments in Common Lisp

Tags: command-line, lisp, common-lisp

How can I get the command line arguments in (specifically in GNU, if there are any differences) Common Lisp?

Comment: For next googlers: there's the mentioned CLON library, now also the simpler [unix-opts](https://github.com/mrkkrp/unix-opts), and a [tutorial](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#parsing-command-line-arguments).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are scripting with CLisp. You can create a file containing

```
#! /usr/local/bin/clisp
(format t "~&~S~&" *args*)
```

Make it executable by running

```
$ chmod 755 <filename>
```

Running it gives

```
$ ./<filename>
NIL
$ ./<filename> a b c
("a" "b" "c")
$ ./<filename> "a b c" 1 2 3
("a b c" "1" "2" "3")
```

Comment: the link in this post is no longer viable. :(

Comment: this is super cool. but how can i make data from the strings? my function is used to inputs like this (unique '(a b c c d d d e f)) and it doesn't work with strings :O .. i tried to (mapcar #'make-symbol *args*) but that doesn't seem to do the job

Answer (score 26):

http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/os.html provides some insight

```
  (defun my-command-line ()
  (or 
   #+CLISP *args*
   #+SBCL *posix-argv*  
   #+LISPWORKS system:*line-arguments-list*
   #+CMU extensions:*command-line-words*
   nil))
```

is what you are looking for, I think.

(edit): see the newer Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html

Comment: (or FOO nil) is equivalent to FOO, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but when you have your FOO conditionally read, it's, possibly, good to have a fall-back. But, then, the value of (or) is, not entirely surprising, NIL (just as the value of (and) is T).

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for `clisp` for me: `*** - OR: variable *ARGS* has no value`

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about Clisp or GCL? Seems like in GCL the command line arguments get passed in `si::*command-args*`.

Answer (score 3):

In SBCL,we can use `sb-ext:*posix-argv*` to get the argv from a Common Lisp script. `sb-ext:*posix-argv*` is a list holding all the arguments, the first member of the list is the script filename.

Comment: I'm not sure this works anymore. I get the error message 'Symbol "POSIX-ARGV" not found in the SB-EXT package.'

Comment: should be  sb-ext:*posix-argv*, in the old text, the \*something\* worked as a style. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

A portable way is `uiop:command-line-arguments` (available in ASDF3, shipped by default in all major implementations).

Libraries-wise, there is the mentioned Clon library that abstracts mechanisms for each implementation, and now also the simpler [unix-opts](https://github.com/mrkkrp/unix-opts), and a [tutorial on the Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#parsing-command-line-arguments).

```
(ql:quickload "unix-opts")

(opts:define-opts
    (:name :help
       :description "print this help text"
       :short #\h
       :long "help")
    (:name :nb
       :description "here we want a number argument"
       :short #\n
       :long "nb"
       :arg-parser #'parse-integer) ;; <- takes an argument
    (:name :info
       :description "info"
       :short #\i
       :long "info"))
```

Then actual parsing is done with `(opts:get-opts)`, which returns two values: the options, and the remaining free arguments.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021843/31615, each implementation has its own mechanism.  The usual way to deal with this is to use a wrapper library that presents a unified interface to you.

Such a library can provide further assistance in not only reading things in, but also converting them and giving helpful output to the user.  A quite complete package is CLON (not to be confused with CLON or CLON, sorry), the [Command Line Options Nuker](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~didier/software/lisp/clon.php), which also brings extensive documentation.  There are others, though, should your needs be more lightweight, for example, [command-line-arguments](https://github.com/fare/command-line-arguments) and [apply-argv](https://github.com/pve1/apply-argv).

The packages in quicklisp for these are named `net.didierverna.clon`, `command-line-arguments`, and `apply-argv`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for it on SBCL (2.1.11.debian):

```
(defun main ()
    (let (
        (args sb-ext:*posix-argv*))

    (format t "args = ~a~%" args)))

(main)
```